# Leg pain after exercises

Tags: injury

I have been exercising at home for the past 4-5 months. 3 times a week. My legs exercise routine is 60 bridges and 12x5 leg raises. The  day before yesterday i did exactly the same routine , and i felt the normal ''pain'' i always feel.I didn't do any exercises yesterday because i was still hurting a little bit. But this morning when i woke up, my right leg, felt like it had been removed . I can't lay on my bed , i can't sit, i can't walk i cannot do anything because it hurts so bad. This is the 1st time ever i feel this kind of pain. The parts that hurt are, one inch below my booty to my knee. What should I do? I need immediate answers . Should i see a doctor? I have been putting some relaxing cremes on my leg but they haven't worked out AT ALL. I haven't massaged because it hurts even if I touch it. I'm literally suffering and i do not know what to do. Please reply as soon as possible , because i need some more information about what could be possibly going on with my leg before i visit a doctor. I am looking forward , Donna

Comment: Yes see your doctor.  Whether it is a pulled muscle, a nerve irritation or something else, intense pain such as you describe is worthy of a visit to your doctor.

Comment: What you describe sounds like [Sciatica](http://www.spine-health.com/conditions/sciatica/what-you-need-know-about-sciatica) or some other nerve impingement.  I would strongly recommend you take the advice of BackInShapeBuddy.

Answer (score 2):

**Pain**

If you have possible injuries, you should absolutely consult a doctor, and not the internet. You will quite probably need a scan of some sort.

If I had to venture a guess, I'd say you've pulled a muscle, or possibly torn a tendon/ligament, depending on the intensity of the pain. 60 bridges sounds like a possible cause here. Oh, and about those bridges...

**Leg day**

What I can tell you for sure though, is that your leg exercises are quite poorly laid out. Bridges work well for glutes as an isolation exercise, but it does virtually nothing for your legs. And leg raises is an abdominal exercise. This does nothing at all for your legs.

For legs, you should look into various squatting techniques. There is plenty to be done with bodyweight alone. [Here is a list of 40 different variations.](http://greatist.com/move/squat-variations-you-need-to-know) You absolutely do NOT need to do all of these every time, but pick 3-4 of them each time you have leg day.

If you need more advice on setting up an at-home exercise plan, you can add another question.

Comment: +1 for "leg exercises are quite poorly laid out". Had partially torn ligaments before -2nd degree-, she wouldnt be able to walk properly if that were the case, plus leg would be very swollen as well. Sounds more like a bad strain -1rst degree-.